# Why does the heatmap of this gene expression data don't show a decent clustering here?

Tags: r, hierarchical-clustering, genetics, dendrogram, heatmap

[image]

The heatmap has samples in columns and probesets/features in the rows. The genes are already selected based on a very low p-value threshold using 2 sample t-test on the two phenotypic subgroups of the samples (colored as red and blue in the horizontal color bar between the top dendrogram and heatmap). So I would be expecting a very good clustering in the heatmap vertically. But here what I see is that there is a red group on top, then a green, then red and then a green stacked horizontally. The heatmap is produced using heatmap.2 of gplots. The code is :

```
heatmap.2(matrixData, col=redgreen(75), ColSideColors=sampleColors,
          key=TRUE, symkey=FALSE, density.info="none", trace="none",
          labRow = F, labCol = F)
```

Comment: Difficult to say. You could try a different linkage method, to see if you get better results. Are you using the Euclidean distance or some correlation for the distance matrix?

Comment: maybe the 2 phenotypic subgroups do not differ that much w.r.t gene expression? coding error, mixed up the samples?

Comment: Are you trying to group together observations or features?

Comment: Just the samples (the columns).